# how to get the count of duplicates created using JQrelcopy in javascript?

Tags: jquery, yii

I have a form with JQrelcopy extension

and have two fields fromtime and totime in the copy class. I know I can get it in controller using $_POST.

> But I want to get the count of duplicates using script

if I know the count then only I can place it in the loops and traverse
through every values.
the two fields which I used are (fromtime and totime) CHtml::dropdownfields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the same class on all duplicates, like this:

```
<input type="text" class="duplicate-field" name="field1" />
<input type="text" class="duplicate-field" name="field2" />
<input type="text" class="duplicate-field" name="field3" />
```

then you can easily count their occurence:

`var duplicate_count = $(".duplicate-field").length;`